# MySQL query that checks if two user ids are friends

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which maps friendships between two user ids. The table has two columns userid1 and userid2. 
If userid1 adds userid2 as a friend then that will be one row.
If userid2 adds userid1 as a friend then that will be another row added to the table
This is similar to how Facebook needs both users to add each other as friends before a friendship is established.

How do I query the table so I find out all the userid pairs that have added each other as friends?

Comment: That's kind of a strange request - when would you ever need to show that data? And how would you format it? Something like "get all friends of user Joe Blow" would make more sense.

Comment: I want to check which new friendships have been established recently.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that facebook just has one row per "friendship", which would make your job easier. Having two rows that are opposite just adds unnecessary confusion IMO

Comment: I should have called this table as a friend request table. I think that would have made it clearer why I need two rows for each friendship

Comment: You should have a friend request table AND a friendship table. The friendship table should have one row per friendship with a user_1 and user_2 column, and obviously the creation time of the row since you need that for your query. Then it's just a matter of joining the users table on user_1 and user_2

Comment: Yes that is what should be done. Thanks for helping clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could join back to the same table.  Something like the below;

```
SELECT a.userid1, a.userid2
FROM friendship a
INNER JOIN friendship b
ON a.userId1 = b.userId2 AND b.userId1 = a.userId2
```